# adjust contrast of an image to negative percentages in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, contrast

I need to change contrast of an image to negative percentage.

I use `imcontrast()`, but when I try to set negative percentage it raises the below error:

```
percentage must be a number between 0 and 100
```

but I need to reduce contrast -20%. 
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are posing the problem wrong.

There is no such thing as a negative contrast. Theoretically yes but when implementing no. You just need to re-think your problem and then use `imcontrast` to convert the range of values of your image.

Try to use first this Image Contrast Tool - http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/adjusting-image-contrast-using-the-adjust-contrast-tool.html

Only then apply the code - http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imcontrast.html

Comment: sorry I am a bit new in image processing, in some article image contrast reduced -20% as a watermark attack. I did this in "xnview" too, but now I need to implement it in matlab. I even dont know imcontrast() is a proper way to do that